ComputeError: TypeError: np.mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
When I try to use numpy.mean within a polars dataframe I get an error message:
import numpy as np #v2.1.0
import polars as pl #v1.6.0
from polars import col

TRIALS = 1
SIMS = 10

np.random.seed(42)

df = pl.DataFrame({
  'a': np.random.binomial(TRIALS, .45, SIMS),
  'b': np.random.binomial(TRIALS, .5, SIMS),
  'c': np.random.binomial(TRIALS, .55, SIMS)
})

df.head()

df.with_columns(
  z_0 = np.mean(col("a"))
).head()

TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
Adding an explicit axis argument will not change the error.
df.with_columns(
  z_0 = np.mean(a=col("a"), axis=0)
).head()

TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
I know that I could complete this computation with:
df.with_columns(
  z_0 = ncol("a").mean()
).head()

But I am trying to understand how non-polars functions work within polars.

Why would you think that adding an argument that it says isn't supported help?

I don't see how you could be getting that error from the code you posted. Please post the full traceback of the error.

@Barmar I get the same error, here is the traceback: https://pastebin.com/eSqxtK9j

Please use the "Edit" button to add it to the question. But since the error is happening internally to numpy, it seems like a numpy bug.

Make sure your numpy is up to date.

@Barmar I'm not the OP, I'll let them add their own traceback (perhaps it's different).

np.mean isn't an Expression. You have to use map_batches or better yet just use pl.col('a').mean()

@DeanMacGregor df.select(pl.col("a").map_batches(np.mean)) doesn't work either, it returns ComputeError: TypeError: Series.mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. Sure the built-in .mean() function works, but the question of OP is about using the Numpy version.

hmm it might be a bug that you have to do this explicitly but df.select(pl.col('a').map_batches(lambda x: np.mean(x.to_numpy()))) works

cumsum just works, ie. df.select(pl.col('a').map_batches(np.cumsum)), not sure why np.mean doesn't.

It is very odd. The full error I get is: TypeError: Expr.mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' - which suggests Polars Expr.mean() is being called. But the traceback points to a line in numpy/core/fromnumeric.py - perhaps some issue with the ufunc dispatching stuff?

@DeanMacGregor that's odd indeed. Interestingly polars does not have a cumsum function, instead it's called cum_sum. Also, np.average works, polars has no average function. It seems to me as if the wrong function is being called in polars when there is an overlap in naming.

Python styling guide is to snake case method names but not if it's going to be a breaking change for old libraries. polars is a new library so they're following the style guide whereas old libraries are favoring keeping consistency. polars does have average but it's called mean. I can't imagine how the difference between the methods working and not working is their name.

I've checked a few more numpy functions (https://pastebin.com/Rcp1UPPL), and while a pattern appears of the np function either existing as a polars function of the same name or working, it's not conclusive: https://pastebin.com/LnjanBRi

This z_0 = pl.mean("a") worked for me. Sort of lends credence to idea that Polars is not picking the correct function. You should file an issue here Polars issues.

This can be done but is rather involved, because you have to use UDFs and call numpy functions through it: df.select(pl.col("a").map_batches(lambda x: np.mean(x.to_numpy())))
